# ld: cannot find lc -ERROR

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld

My purpose is to link two codes using my own linker script and for the same, i have created a simple linker script (All help from around the internet)
This is my linker script, "link.lds"

```
SECTIONS
{
   . = 0x10000;
   .text : { *(.text) }
   . = 0x8000000;
   .data : { *(.data) }
   .bss : { *(.bss) }
}
```

and my two simple C codes are as follows.
1) l1.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern int a;
int main()
{
printf("%d",a);
return 0;
}
```

AND
2) l2.c

```
int a=111;
```

The commands that i use are:

```
gcc -c l1.c l2.c
ld -o output -T link.lds l1.o l2.o -lc
```

After following the above steps, I encounter the following error:

```
ld:cannot find lc
```

on removing lc,

```
undefined reference to printf().
```

I also tried using -L/dirname which took me back to the undef reference to printf error.

MAY I GET SOME HELP AND GUIDANCE ON THE SAME...
PS- Im aware i could have gone conceptually wrong and/or might not be aware about the correct sequence of linker execution/working.
Any help on the same would be highly appreciated.
Many Thanks!

Comment: is this some exercise learning GNU ld? If not, just use `gcc` for linking, it will do all the "dirty work" for you.

Comment: Why do you need custom script? If the goal is to simply link two object into an executable, no linker script is required. Error with -lc means your libc.a  can not be found in the linker search path. Do you know where it is on your system?

Comment: I have edited the question. I purposely want to use a custom linker script for a larger problem statement. Also, i found the path of libc.a, tried adding it using -L / -l , but in vain, it still prompts the "Undefined reference to printf()" error.

Comment: Please remove the C++ tag. Also, you have found the wrong libc, use `gcc --print-file-name-libc.so` to to see the correct path. Also, when you fix the library path, you will be able to create an executable but it won't work. Use `gcc -v l1.o l2.o -o output` to see which parts you are missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are invoking `ld` directly, no default libraries or default library search paths
are supplied, as they would be if `ld` were invoked indirectly by the `gcc` tool-driver
in the usual way.

So as well as telling `ld` explicitly to link `libc` (`-lc`), you must explicitly
*also* tell it where to find `libc`, using the `-L` option. (It seems that you
think `L<path>` is an *alternative* to `-l<libname>`. It's not.)

Therefore find out where `libc.so` is located on your system. You can do this with:

```
realpath $(gcc --print-file-name libc.so)
```

(Note, not `--print-file-name-libc.so`. There is a typo in @n.m's comment)

Suppose it is `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so`, as on my system. Then run:

```
ld -o output -T link.lds l1.o l2.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lc
```

That will solve the problem in your question (but not necessarily any others).

Comment: Hello mike, got busy with other modules and back to this one now. It still prompts the same error. Any solution for the same? I did exactly what you proposed.

Comment: it is the same. ld:cannot find lc

Comment: @ArjunJain That is the error message. What is the commandline that causes it?

Comment: I was having a typo in the command line. Your command line works just fine. Thank you. Also i wanted to know how to decipher a linker map file. What does each field mean? Any guidance would be helpful. Thanks much